# How to download com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar

Tags: websphere, orb, was

How to download com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar?
I was going through IBM developerworks and IBM support site. But I am not finding this jar for working with standalone spring boot applications.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/586313#SDK80 this has IBM websphere downloads but thin client jar is not present here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the actual question? Please follow the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question

Comment: There is no separate download for that jar. You either need to download "WebSphere Application Server full profile" or "WebSphere Application Server Supplements" or get that jar from the environment that you will be connecting to with your spring app.